# BigQuery: how to sample running totals over time

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table recording when items were purchased from a store. It contains an ItemID and a timestamp. I am interested in the running totals for each item purchased. I have this query which generates the running totals:

```
SELECT ItemID,timestamp,count(*)
OVER
  (PARTITION BY ItemID
  ORDER BY timestamp ASC, ItemID) AS runningtotal
from 
(
  SELECT * FROM [mydb.purchases] 
)
ORDER BY timestamp
```

This table has hundreds of thousands of rows.
What I would now like to do is take a period (eg a week) and get 100 samples of the running totals for each ItemID over that week (in order to plot a graph without too many datapoints). 
I'm not sure how to do this. I can get 100 samples overall by filtering on something like "where (rownumber % (rowcount / 100) = 0" but how can I do this for every ItemID in the table? Do I need to do multiple subqueries for each ItemID and then create a union? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using Standard SQL you can first collect sample of 100 timestamps using `LIMIT` clause inside `ARRAY_AGG` function:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT ItemID, timestamp, COUNT(*)
OVER (PARTITION BY ItemID ORDER BY timestamp ASC) AS running_total
FROM (
SELECT ItemID, ARRAY_AGG(timestamp LIMIT 100) timestamps
FROM `mydb.purchases`) t, t.timestamps timestamp
ORDER BY timestamp
```

If this doesn't do random sampling you could use `RAND()` to reshuffle timestamps:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT ItemID, timestamp, COUNT(*)
OVER (PARTITION BY ItemID ORDER BY timestamp ASC) AS running_total
FROM (
SELECT ItemID, ARRAY_AGG(timestamp ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 100) timestamps
FROM `mydb.purchases`)  t, t.timestamps timestamp
ORDER BY timestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

Below does exactly what you described in a sense of sampling
I left `selecting week worse of data` aspect out as it is trivial

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT
  ItemID,
  timestamp,
  runningtotal  
FROM (
  SELECT 
    ItemID, 
    timestamp, 
    COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemID ORDER BY timestamp ASC) AS runningtotal,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ItemID ORDER BY timestamp ASC) AS rownumber,
    COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY ItemID) AS rowcount
  FROM `mydb.purchases`
)
WHERE MOD(rownumber, CAST(rowcount/100 AS INT64)) = 0
-- ORDER BY ItemID, timestamp
```